# Paypal paying back users

Tags: php, paypal, payment

We've integrated Paypal on website of client for accepting payments.

All is fine.

But client wants to be able to pay users of his website back if they have earned some bounces/scores etc.

By  now we have implemented such system:

1. If user of website should get paid  - admin of website gets notification about it in admin panel
2. Admin looks manually at data of client and decides whether he pays or not (pressing approve or deny button)

It looks  so:

[image]

Client is not satisfied with such system, saying it will get tedious and boring business when he gets many users (unlikely, but this is not the point).

I wonder. Is it possible somehow to automatise this process? He would like only to press "Approve" button and  user should be paid immediately.

At first I've thought about using the same code that I use for accepting payments: 
 [image]

But when I accept payments, I use address of created shop. Usual users of paypal don't have shops. Well, this is all pretty confusing.

Any links or advice are appreciated.  Because I'm not sure whether such thing is possible or good at all or perhaps I should say client that it can't be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a payment programatically using [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/) or [Adaptive Payments (Implicit Payments)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/). Either of these methods is a little more advanced, and you have to make an API call to the PayPal server.

MassPay has some restrictions US or CANADA business accounts only.
AdaptivePayments requires the account to go through an application process on http://developer.paypal.com and http://apps.paypal.com